# Simple Products Custom Options price sorting - magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, filter, magento-1.9.2.1, price-sorting

magento 1.9.2 - how to get simple products custom options price for price slider sorting in sidebar and load product collection in the list page. by default magento not sorting custom options price